# How to train a custom keypoint detector for drone pose estimation. Detectron2

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, keypoint, detectron

Because I couldn't find the answer elsewhere I decided to describe my issue here.
I'm trying to create ***keypoints detector of the Eachine TrashCan Drone for estimating its pose***.
I followed some tutorials. The first one was with the TensorFlow ObjectDetectionAPI and because I couldn't find a solution with it I tried to use ***detectron2***. Everything was fine until I needed to register my own dataset to retrain a model.

I am running the code on Google Colab and using coco-annotator for making annotations (https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator/)

I do not think that I wrongly annotated my dataset, but who knows so I will show in the hyperlink below to present it a bit for you: [Picture with annotations made by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHPXB.jpg)

I used that code to registrate the data:

```
from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances
register_coco_instances("TrashCan_train", {}, "./TrashCan_train/mask_train.json", "./TrashCan_train")
register_coco_instances("TrashCan_test", {}, "./TrashCan_test/mask_test.json", "./TrashCan_test")
```

This one is not giving me an error but when I'm trying to begin the training process with that code:

```
from detectron2.engine import DefaultTrainer

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-Keypoints/keypoint_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN = ("TrashCan_train",)
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("TrashCan_test")
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = ("detectron2://COCO-Keypoints/keypoint_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849621/model_final_a6e10b.pkl")  # Let training initialize from model zoo
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.00025  # pick a good LR
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 25    # 300 iterations seems good enough for this toy dataset; you may need to train longer for a practical dataset
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 128   # faster, and good enough for this toy dataset (default: 512)
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 1  # liczba klas

os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg) 
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()
```

I end up with this:

```
WARNING [07/14 14:36:52 d2.data.datasets.coco]: 
Category ids in annotations are not in [1, #categories]! We'll apply a mapping for you.

[07/14 14:36:52 d2.data.datasets.coco]: Loaded 5 images in COCO format from ./mask_train/mask_train.json

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-f4f5153c62a1> in <module>()
     14 
     15 os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
---> 16 trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg)
     17 trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
     18 trainer.train()

7 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/detectron2/data/datasets/coco.py in load_coco_json(json_file, image_root, dataset_name, extra_annotation_keys)
    183             obj["bbox_mode"] = BoxMode.XYWH_ABS
    184             if id_map:
--> 185                 obj["category_id"] = id_map[obj["category_id"]]
    186             objs.append(obj)
    187         record["annotations"] = objs

KeyError: 9
```

This is where you can download my files:

https://github.com/BrunoKryszkiewicz/EachineTrashcan-keypoints/blob/master/TrashCan_Datasets.zip

and where will you find my Colab notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AlLZxrR64irms9mm-RiZ4DNOs2CaAEZ9?usp=sharing

I created such a small dataset because first of all, I wanted to go through threw the training process. If I will manage to do that I will make my dataset bigger.

Now I'm not even sure if is it possible to retrain a human keypoint model for obtaining keypoints of a drone-like object or any other. I need to say that I'm pretty new on the topic so I am asking for your understanding.
If you know any tutorials for creating a custom (non-human) keypoint detector I will be grateful for any information.

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Right off the bat I can notice some differences between your `json` file and the way that COCO dataset is described [here](https://cocodataset.org/#format-data) the official coco website. Some keys are superfluous such as "keypoint colors". However in my experience with `detectron2` superfluous keys are ignored and do not pose a problem.

The actual error message you are getting is due to the fact that you have annotations that have `category_id` that `detectron's` mapping does not account for.

There is only 1 category in the "categories" part of your `mask_test.json` file, but you have 2 annotations one with `category_id = 9` and another with `category_id` = 11.

What *detectron2* does is, it counts the number of categories in the *categories* field of the json and if they aren't numbered 1 through *n* it generates it's own mapping in your case it transforms 11 (your present id) into 1 (both in *annotations* and *categories* fields), but has no idea what to do with the annotation that has a category 9.  And this is causes the error message on the line 185 `obj["category_id"] = id_map[obj["category_id"]]` because there simply isn't a mapping from 9 to whatever.

One thing to note is that **AS FAR AS I CAN TELL** (would be nice to ask how to do this on the github page of `detectron2`) you cannot train keypoint detection with multiple "classes" of keypoints using detectron2

Anyway the solution to your problem is fairly simple, just have one category with `id: 1` in the *categories* field, and write change `category_id` of everything in the *annotations* field to 1. And run your training

**EDIT**: you will also need to change a few other `config`s for in the `cfg` for this to work. Namely `TEST.KEYPOINT_OKS_SIGMAS = sigmas_used_for_evaluation_per_keypoint` `MODEL.ROI_KEYPOINT_HEAD.NUM_KEYPOINTS = number_of_keypoints_in_your_category`
And what is more you need to have `keypoint_flip_map`, `keypoint_names` and `keypoint_connection_rules` in the metadata of your dataset.
To set this you can use `MetadataCatalog.get('name_of_your_set').set(obj)`
where obj will be your metadata described above

Comment: How could I find config for keypoint detection in detectron2?

Comment: It's in the configs folder in yhe Git repo.

Comment: @Vahagn Tumanyan can you please explain how to calculate TEST.KEYPOINT_OKS_SIGMAS (list of floats) it's unclear for me? thank you

Comment: @JammingTheBits The official MSCOCO dataset gives defaults for human-skeleton keypoints. These numbers are basically how close (in what epsilon radius) should each point of the template be to the ground truth position so we consider it a "Correct" point. 

They have calculated they're own through experimentation and trial and error. Basically an eye can't be too far away, but a point on the knee can have more of a leeway. 

There's no specific way to calculate them, you just have to adjust to your own problem.